# RecurrenceTable with a recurrence function of two variables

Tags: difference-equations

I have to calculate the cool down process of a regenerative heat exchanger. I solved the problem in Excel before, but now I want to do it with *Mathematica*. I want to create a table with the variables t and z. For `t = 0`, there is a function which gives the temperature for each layer z. For `z = 0`, there is another function which gives the temperature for the first layer for each t. the rest of the table should be calculated layer by layer, so that z is constant while t goes form `t0` to `tend`, then z should increase 1 step and so on. I tried out some simple code, but it didn't work. What's worng? Are there any other ways to solve my problem?

```
RecurrenceTable[{
  T[t + 1, z + 1] == T[t, z + 1] + T[t + 1, z], 
  T[t + 1, 0] == T[t, 0]/2, 
  T[0, z] == z + 2
  }, 
  T, {t, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 4}] // Grid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved almost directly from your attempt by defining a recursive function. I've replaced your variable `T` with `temp` (for temperature), and added one more boundary condition. Something must be specified for `temp[0,0]` in order to have a well-defined function, `temp[0,0] = 2` makes sense for consistency with the `t=0` case.

```
temp[t_, z_] := temp[t - 1, z] + temp[t, z - 1];
temp[t_, 0] := temp[t - 1, 0]/2;
temp[0, z_] := z + 2;
temp[0, 0] := 2;
```

You can now ask for the values you want:

```
{temp[2,1], temp[5,6], temp[3,1]}

{9/2, 18017/16, 19/4}
```

or build a table of many

```
allTemps = Table[temp[i, j], {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, 4}];
N[allTemps]//TableForm
```

[image]

The OP noted that this runs slowly for large values. With luck, this can be sped up using the memoization trick, which is quite easy to program:

```
Clear[temp];
temp[t_, z_] := temp[t, z] = temp[t - 1, z] + temp[t, z - 1];
temp[t_, 0] := temp[t, z] = temp[t - 1, 0]/2;
temp[0, z_] := temp[0, z] = z + 2;
temp[0, 0] := temp[0, 0] = 2;
```

What this is doing is to cache the values that have already been computed (rather than recomputing them each time), hence trading off memory for execution speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried it out for imax = 10 and jmax = 10 and it worked for my actual more complicated problem as well. The only problem is that there are 760 steps for z and 250 for t. So after ten minutes I had to abort the evaluation, because my laptop seems too slow for this calculation. I have to try it on my desktop.

Comment: You can probably speed this up greatly if you wish. The technique called memoization is easy to do. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: It works:) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is using loops:

```
grid = {};
tab1 = Table[z + 2, {z, 0, 4}];
AppendTo[grid, tab1];
t = 1;
While[t <= 6,
tab = {};
z = 0;
While[z <= 4,
If[z == 0, AppendTo[tab, tab1[[z + 1]]/2], 
AppendTo[tab, tab1[[z + 1]] + tab[[-1]]]];
z++];
tab1 = tab;
AppendTo[grid, tab1];
t++];
Grid[grid // N]
```

[image: output table]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also tried out your way to solve my problem. Now I have to check if it is faster than bills solution.

Comment: You can optimize my code a bit more if you rewrite the inner loop so that you first create a new `tab = {tab1[[z + 1]]/2]}`, start with `z = 1` and then you can get rid of the `If[]` test.