# Problem with RecurrenceTable of two variables

Tags: recursion, core-language, difference-equations

Let we have simple recursive function:

```
Clear[recFun];
recFun[1, k_] := 1;
recFun[n_, 1] := 1;
recFun[n_, k_] := recFun[n, k - 1] + recFun[n - 1, k - 1];

recFun[2,3]
Out: 3
```

But this code not work:

```
Clear[rf]; RecurrenceTable[{rf[n, k] == rf[n, k - 1] + rf[n - 1, k - 1], 
      rf[1, k] == 1, rf[n, 1] == 1}, rf, {n, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
```

I've read [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/recurrencetable-with-a-recurrence-function-of-two-variables), but TS was answered *how to do recursion*.
Why `RecurrenceTable` not work remained unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```mathematica
Clear[rf]; 
RecurrenceTable[{rf[n, k] == 
    If[k >= 2 && n >= 2, rf[n, k - 1] + rf[n - 1, k - 1], 1], 
   rf[n, 1] == 1, rf[1, k] == 1}, rf, {n, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}] // Grid
```

```
1   1   1   1   1
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   4   7   11
1   2   4   8   15
1   2   4   8   16
```

---

This doesn't work:

```
Clear[rf];
RecurrenceTable[{rf[n, k] == 
    If[k >= 2 && n >= 2, rf[n, k - 1] + rf[n - 1, k - 1], 1], 
   rf[1, k] == 1, rf[n, 1] == 1}, rf, {n, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}] // Grid
```